# How can I track HTML5 browser features (modernizr) using Google Analytics?

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, modernizr

I've been using Modernizr for a short while to style my site based on the user's browser functions. I've also been using Google Analytics for some time, but haven't done a whole lot with custom variables..

Basically, I'd like to combine these two features; I'd like to report to Google what features the user's browser supports. In Google analytics, I'd like to see what percentage of my users have browsers that support SVG, for instance, or have flexible box support.

How should this problem be approached? I'm aware that Google has a very limited number of Custom Variables at my disposal. If I put all of the body's final classes into a string and post it as one custom variable, will I be able to segment my data appropriately within Google?

Thanks for any ideas or insight.

Comment: this topic tells you how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982255/can-i-determine-html5-support-in-my-users-browsers-with-google-analytics

Comment: @Sander So it looks like it's not possible to track all of the features Modernizr tests; just a few at a time. I was hoping for a way to work around Google Analytic's 5-variable limit. At any rate, thanks for the link; it's a wonder why that didn't show up when I searched earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t easily track all of Modernizr’s individual features and make them easily usable with Google Analytics.

However, you can use the [Modernizr results table](http://www.browserscope.org/user/tests/table/agt1YS1wcm9maWxlcnINCxIEVGVzdBib2KQGDA) to get an overview of what each individual browser supports, and then cross-reference that with your audience's browsers from Google Analytics.

Comment: It may not be the direct answer to the question, but it is the solution to the overall problem, and a creative one at that. Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Google analytics can be called manually in Javascript using calls such as `pageTracker._trackPageview();`. It's fairly simple code. See the Analytics API manual for the other function calls that are available and example code.

Modernizr sets a Javascript variable for each property it checks. It should be simple enough to write an `if()` block to look at that property and make different `_trackPageview` calls dependant on the result of the `if()`.

Comment: I'm afraid I wasn't descriptive enough; I'm hoping to be able to track all of the features Modernizr detects. Since Google Analytics only allows five variables to be set at a time, I'm now wondering if segmentation would be possible if the entire body classset were used as a string in an Analytics variable, or if Google would limit the variable length.